# CSS for deployed ear on websphere application server not working

Tags: java, html, css, websphere

I have a web application deployed as EAR from websphere integration developer on a websphere application server. When I run it on server, everything works fine, but the css file doesn't load. It gives this error:

> Servlet has become temporarily unavailable for service

The strangest thing is that I also have images that have the same source as the css file, meaning : `<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/theme/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

The path for the image is this :

```
<IMG src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/theme/images/image.gif" />
```

So the image is loading, while the css is giving the error from above.

Can you please help me? I searched all around google but I didn't quite found any helpful answers to this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into http://www.coderanch.com/t/79516/Websphere/Servlet-temporarily-unavailable-service. It seems it might be an issue with rebuilding or the resource getting locked.

Comment: Restart your server or machine this will solve the problem.